# Spark DataFrame - How to partition the data based on condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Have some employee data set. in that i need to partition based employee salary based on some condition. Created DataFrame and converted to Custom DataFrame Object. Created Custom Partition for salary.

```
class SalaryPartition(override val numPartitions: Int) extends Partitioner {

  override def getPartition(key: Any): Int =
    {
      import com.csc.emp.spark.tutorial.PartitonObj._
      key.asInstanceOf[Emp].EMPLOYEE_ID match {
        case salary if salary < 10000 => 1
        case salary if salary >= 10001 && salary < 20000 => 2
        case _ => 3
      }

    }

}
```

Question how can i invoke\call my custome partition. Couldn't find partitionBy in dataframe. Have any alternative way?

Comment: Team.. have any solution

Comment: New column can be created with function with values (1,2,3) and then column used in "df.repartition". Also such partitioning looks strange, maybe, other options (without partitioning) will be better for resolve task.

Comment: @ pasha701 ..Can you please explain more.. partially understand your statment. understood that add new column which will tell the partition bucket and use in df.repartition.  How to use repartition.. can u please explain in code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just code for my comment:

```
val empDS = List(Emp(5, 1000), Emp(4, 15000), Emp(3, 30000), Emp(2, 2000)).toDS()
println(s"Original partitions number: ${empDS.rdd.partitions.size}")
println("-- Original partition: data --")
empDS.rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((index, it) => {
  it.foreach(r => println(s"Partition $index: $r")); it
}).count()

val getSalaryGrade = (salary: Int) => salary match {
  case salary if salary < 10000 => 1
  case salary if salary >= 10001 && salary < 20000 => 2
  case _ => 3
}
val getSalaryGradeUDF = udf(getSalaryGrade)
val salaryGraded = empDS.withColumn("salaryGrade", getSalaryGradeUDF($"salary"))

val repartitioned = salaryGraded.repartition($"salaryGrade")
println
println(s"Partitions number after: ${repartitioned.rdd.partitions.size}")
println("-- Reparitioned partition: data --")

repartitioned.as[Emp].rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((index, it) => {
  it.foreach(r => println(s"Partition $index: $r")); it
}).count()
```

Output is:

```
Original partitions number: 2
-- Original partition: data --
Partition 1: Emp(3,30000)
Partition 0: Emp(5,1000)
Partition 1: Emp(2,2000)
Partition 0: Emp(4,15000)

Partitions number after: 5
-- Reparitioned partition: data --
Partition 1: Emp(3,30000)
Partition 3: Emp(5,1000)
Partition 3: Emp(2,2000)
Partition 4: Emp(4,15000)
```

**Note:** guess, several partitions possible with the same "salaryGrade".

**Advice:** "groupBy" or similar looks like more reliable solution.

For stay with Dataset entities, "groupByKey" can be used:

```
empDS.groupByKey(x => getSalaryGrade(x.salary)).mapGroups((index, it) => {
  it.foreach(r => println(s"Group $index: $r")); index
}).count()
```

Output:

```
Group 1: Emp(5,1000)
Group 3: Emp(3,30000)
Group 1: Emp(2,2000)
Group 2: Emp(4,15000)
```

Comment: perfect.. let me test. can you please explain how to use "group By" option